# Looping javascript object to print data

Tags: javascript, loops, nested, javascript-objects, traversal

I have a javascript object that I would like to traverse and print data based off 1 common category.

Javascript object:

```
var $states = {
"AL" : {
  "longname": "Alabama",
  "lawOne": "Alabama Law 1",
  "lawTwo": "Alabama Law 2",
  "lawThree": "Alabama Law 3",
  "region" : "Southeast"
},
"AK" : {
  "longname": "Alaska",
  "lawOne": "Alaska Law 1",
  "lawTwo": "Alaska Law 2",
  "lawThree": "Alaska Law 3",
  "region" : "Northwest"
},
"AZ" : {
  "longname": "Arizona",
  "lawOne": "Arizona Law 1",
  "lawTwo": "Arizona Law 2",
  "lawThree": "Arizona Law 3",
  "region" : "Southwest"
},
etc...
}
```

I am able too loop the array and get as granular as getting the console to log all of the states that are in the same region:

```
for (var key in $states) {
        if ($states.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var $getStateRegion = $states[key].region

            if ($getStateRegion === "Northeast") {
                console.log ($states[key].longname);
            }
        }
    }
```

Once I try to loop through those and print a table with that data is where I am running into an issue. I want to be able to have a  withthe 's longname, lawOne, lawTwo, and lawThree values input in there. What gives? Once I try running a for loops through this is where I'm hitting a roadblock. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Your code is working fine but you are if segment wrong.

change **Northeast** to **Northwest**

Comment: @BeingSunny the issue is that, that currently logs a list of all of the longnames of the state. The goal is to loop through the states in that region and display their laws in different <tr>'s. If I add a for loop that iterates through the regional states, nothing is showing in my browser

Comment: @HoangHieu Not entirely. See above. That is the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

Try the working code below.

```js
var $states = {
"AL" : {
  "longname": "Alabama",
  "lawOne": "Alabama Law 1",
  "lawTwo": "Alabama Law 2",
  "lawThree": "Alabama Law 3",
  "region" : "Southeast"
},
"AK" : {
  "longname": "Alaska",
  "lawOne": "Alaska Law 1",
  "lawTwo": "Alaska Law 2",
  "lawThree": "Alaska Law 3",
  "region" : "Northwest"
},
"AZ" : {
  "longname": "Arizona",
  "lawOne": "Arizona Law 1",
  "lawTwo": "Arizona Law 2",
  "lawThree": "Arizona Law 3",
  "region" : "Southwest"
}
};

var result = {};
Object.keys($states).forEach(function(key) {
  if ($states[key]["region"] === "Southwest") {
    result[key] = $states[key];
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Before I continue, I would like to point out that you are using a for..in loop, but newer versions of Javascript support the for..of loop also, so this is something you may want to consider.  The difference is that the for..in loop gives you the keys of the object, and the for..of loop gives you the values, so it shortens the code by skipping the step where you write something to the effect of:

```
for( var index in array ){
  var currentObject = array[ index ];
}
```

The secret to your solution is in how you handle the DOM, and there are many ways to do this. I will show you one, but it is not necessarily the fastest or the best. I recommend playing around with different DOM manipulations to find the one that works best for you.

First, we know how to get a record, so the javascript aspect of looping, you have that handled...

Next, we need to create the table.... I will assume that you want four columns based on your description, but you could easily adjust this to put the state name and one law on each line, which would probably be a better design allowing a variable number of laws.

The html would look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>State</th><th>Law 1</th><th>Law 2</th><th>Law 3</th></tr>
    <!-- Here is where we would create new html for each state -->
</table>
```

Your loop then would need to add to this html by creating several lines that appear as:

```
<tr><td>[State]</td><td>[Law1]</td><td>[Law2]</td><td>[Law3]</td><tr>
```

We will use string manipulation of the DOM, because it is a good place to start, because it is most similar to what you would write by hand.

We will break the table into three parts: the header, the body and the footer.

```
var header = "<table><tr><th>State</th><th>Law 1</th><th>Law 2</th><th>Law 3</th></tr>";

var body   = ""; //this is where we add the data

var footer = "</table>";
```

Now, on the loop, we will create each line as needed and add it to the body:

```
for( var index in stateObj ){
      ...error checking occurs here...
      var state = stateObj[ index ];
      var stateColumn = "<td>" + state.longname + "</td>";
      var law1Col = "<td>" + state.lawOne + "</td>";
      var law2Col = "<td>" + state.lawTwo + "</td>";
      var law3Col = "<td>" + state.lawThree + "</td>";
      var row = "<tr>" + stateColumn + law1Col + law2Col + law3Col + "</tr>";
      //now that we have a row, we add it to the body
      body += row;  //same as body = body + row;
}
```

After we have the body, we can make our table by combining the header, body and footer:

```
var tableHTML = header + body + footer;
```

And then we find a place to inject it into our document:

```
var outputDiv = document.getElementById( "stateTableData" );
outputDiv.innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

Here is a live example:

```js
var states = {
  PA: {
    longname:"Pennsylvania",
    lawOne:"It is illegal to sing in the shower in apartment buildings within the city limits of Philadelphia",
    lawTwo:"All motorists are required to stop the vehicle for passing horsemen. The vehicle shall be covered with camoflage so as not to scare the horses.",
    lawThree:"Any house having more than four women occupants shall be considered a brothel and shall be in violation of the law."
},
  NJ: {
      longname:"New Jersey",
      lawOne:"There is no such thing as the Mafia",
      lawTwo:"Any reference to the denizens of New Jersey shall be derogatory and degrading, think Jersey Shore",
      lawThree:"There is no escape from New Jersey and we are not a suburb of NYC"
      },
  VA: {
      longname:"Virginia",
      lawOne: "Civil War re-enactments must have the North as the victor.",
      lawTwo: "All roads shall end in Richmond, VA",
      lawThree: "I have run out of silly ideas for this example."
  }
};
function buildTableForState( stateNames ){
    var stateList = stateNames.split(",");
    
    //remove spaces
    for( var i in stateList ){ stateList[i] = stateList[i].trim(); }
    
    //initialize table parts
    var header = "<table><tr><th>State</th><th>Law 1</th><th>Law 2</th><th>Law 3</th></tr>";
    var footer = "</table>";
    var body = "";
    
    //build body
    for( var index in states ){
       if( stateList.indexOf( index ) !== -1 ){
            var currentState = states[index];
            body += buildRowForState( currentState );
       }
    }
    
    //compose and inject table
    var tableHTML = header + body + footer;
    var documentOut = document.getElementById( "outputDiv" );
    documentOut.innerHTML = tableHTML;
}

function submitTable(value){
    buildTableForState( value );
}

function buildRowForState( currentState ){
    var state = makeTableCol( currentState.longname );
    var law1 = makeTableCol( currentState.lawOne );
    var law2 = makeTableCol( currentState.lawTwo );
    var law3 = makeTableCol( currentState.lawThree );
    var row = makeTableRow( [state, law1, law2, law3] );
    return row;
}

function makeTableCol( stringText ){
  return "<td>" + stringText + "</td>";
}

function makeTableRow( arrayColumns ){
  return "<tr>" + arrayColumns.join("") + "</tr>";
}
```

```html
<h1>Table Loader</h1>
<form>
  <p>Use the values "PA", "NJ", and "VA" to generate a table. You can use more than one value by separating them with a comma.</p>
  <input type="text" id="stateNames" name="stateNames" /><br/>
  <button onclick="submitTable(stateNames.value);">Build Table</button>
  <p>Try:
  </p>
  <ul>
  <li>PA</li>
  <li>NJ,VA</li>
  <li>VA,PA,NJ</li>
  </ul>
</form>

<h1>Table Output appears here</h1>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

**NOTE**: Regarding the live code, the HTML is bigger than the display box. In my browser I have to scroll down on the snippit HTML to view the generated table. Either that or expand the snippit window to a full tab to view it in a larger screen.

The above code is simplified, and most coders would tell you not to use HTMLElement.innerHTML, because it is slow, but it is a good place to start. Once you have this down, start practicing with document.create( tagName ), and then use more direct DOM manipulations.

Comment: Very in depth and useful answer! Thanks! Just a few things. When I load this into JSBin or Codepen, the button function brings in a table and then it disappears. I wanted to play with this in a sandbox like atmosphere where I could mess with the DOM a bit. The issue here is that this does not show the data based on common data point. Let's say you were to type in "NJ" in the input field. The desired outcome would show a table with all Northeast states and those laws.

Comment: To play with the code that I gave you, you can use a little "hack" to copy the code to a Stack Overflow snippet editor.  Click "copy snippet to answer". This will replicate my code into a new answer to your question. Then, look beneath that link and click the "edit the above snippit" link.  That will give you a dev environment that lets you play with the javascript, css and html freely.  When you are done, copy and paste that to your own IDE, and delete the draft answer that you created by leaving the page without posting.

Comment: To alter the code to your own needs, you will need to define how your table will look and alter the loop to meet your needs.  Because you are able to output your desired data to the console, I assume that you have the looping part mastered.  If you need help writing those loops, send me the table layout that you want to use, and describe the various ways you want the tables filtered, and I will help you construct the code.

Comment: We can also discuss this in chat if you head to chat.stackoverflow.com, you can find me there today. Specifically in this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign

Comment: Sorry, I got caught up in some other one off requests, and I want to circle back around to this ASAP. Thank you